# Angular get data from API with path variable

Tags: angular, api

I am relatively new to Angular. I am trying to get data from an API. Calling that API, I have to send path variable to that API for searching.
Angular is version 7.
Angular project is running on localhost:4200 while project that returns api is running on localhost:8080.
I have many others API from localhost:8080 running. They all work. Apart from this one, the rest are only get methods with no variable passing.
Currently I am testing on local device. The API's address is

```
http://localhost8080/users/{pathVariable}
```

I tried testing with `http://localhost/users/tester` in Postman and it works, returns a result.

Then I tried to use that url in Angular:

```
   const url='http://localhost:8080/users/testing';
   this.http.get<any>(url).subscribe(data => {this.rowData=data; });
```

I also tried using with variable:

```
    const test='testing';
    const url='http://localhost:8080/users/${test}';
    this.http.get<any>(url).subscribe(data => {this.rowData=data; });
```

But it does not work at all. It is always showing an error and I don't get any data returned.

[image: Error]

How should I solve this error?

Error view in network tab is like this.
[image]

Comment: This error looks more like a Error at your backend. Have you tried using a fake api and checked if you are able to get the data. Check your API again using Postman

Comment: is headers are same as postman.

Comment: While in testing with postman, i used the same url 'http://localhost:8080/users/testing' and it worked, I got return data. I copied that url and tried in angular, the error happens.

Comment: Did you try `http://localhost/users/tester` url or `http://localhost:8000/users/tester` in Postman?

Comment: angular project is running on localhost:4200 and project that return api is running on localhost:8080.. I also tried what you said. It did not work in postman.

Comment: You need to enable `CORS` on your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

From the logs, it seems that you have not configured `CORS` on your server. The fact that `POSTMAN` work is because it does not enforce `CORS` policy while `browsers` does. You should add the following headers to your `public/index.php` or wherever it is located:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

The `*` basically allows every origin while you can replace that with the `origin /url` you've.

**OLD**

I believe there's a typo in your path. You've tested the `users/tester` on `POSTMAN` while hitting `users/testing` in the code. Try fixing that:

```
 const url='http://localhost:8080/users/tester'; //<-- tester but rather testing
 this.http.get<any>(url).subscribe(data => {this.rowData=data; });
```

Comment: At first, I thought like that too. So, I literally copied url from working postman and paste in my angular project. The error is still happening.

Comment: @user8355629 Post a snapshot of a call from network tab.

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost:8080/users/testing
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Content-Length: 8
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2020 06:26:12 GMT
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/querysearch
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site

Comment: That works. Thanks you very much. The new api was in another file of the project which hasn't configure for CORs. Now it works.

Comment: I added CORs permission to angular project port in API generating project. @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600). It is working properly now. Thanks you.